# Ditching local building of websites altogether (Jekyll + Jupyter notebooks + Github pages)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jekyll

I have been working on this project called Curso de Cálculo (http://www.cursodecalculo.com.br) using a combo Jekyll + Github pages + Jupyter notebooks

The template that I'm using is jasper2 (https://github.com/jekyller/jasper2)

and I want to be able to focus on producing content wherever I am. Since I cannot install ruby, jekyll and other required tools on a few computers that I use, I want to know if any of you have already used these tools to "build a jekyll website online", in other words, without having to generate the site locally.

- https://www.netlify.com/
- https://forestry.io/

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is not a Stack Overflow question, because you ask for an opinion.

I have used Forestry.io, Netlify and CloudCannon. All are perfectly capable of doing what you want (building the site online). IMO CloudCannon is the best option. If the free option is not giving you what you want, you can use Forestry.io, as their free tier is more generous. Netlify is way too complex IMO.

Good luck!